# How is the "Any" class works with the "this" variable?

Tags: scala

Please refer this, 
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M1/src/library-aux/scala/Any.scala

The abstract class Any uses "this" self reference for equality test. As far understand "this" is not anything special is scala. How is the "this" value handled in "Any" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is special in Scala. First of all, according to [lexical syntax](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html) section of the language spec, `this` is a reserved keyword. See also the [6.5 This and Super](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#this-and-super) part of the spec that precisely defines the semantics of `this` keyword:

> The expression `this` can appear in the statement part of a template or
>   compound type. It stands for the object being defined by the innermost
>   template or compound type enclosing the reference. If this is a
>   compound type, the type of `this` is that compound type. If it is a
>   template of a class or object definition with simple name `C`, the type
>   of `this` is the same as the type of `C.this`.

So in your case of `Any` class, `this` is a reference to the actual object that the method of equality is called upon.

Answer (score 2):

`this` *is* special in Scala. It refers to the receiver of a message send (if you prefer Smalltalk nomenclature) or the object that the currently executing method was called on (if you prefer C++ nomenclature).

It is equivalent to the [`self`](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(computer_programming)) keyword in Smalltalk, Self, Newspeak, Ruby, Fancy, Object Pascal, Objective-C, Swift, and their relatives or the `this` keyword in Java, C#, VB.NET, ECMAScript, C++, D, PHP, ECMAScript and their relatives or the `Me` keyword in Visual Basic or the `Current` keyword in Eiffel.